# Is there a way to add physics to static animations in AS3(Adobe Animate CC)

Tags: actionscript-3, game-physics, animate-cc

I made a simple swing animation in adobe animate cc(AS 3.0) but the problem is that user needs to interact with it causing gravitational reactions.For e.g:When the user interacts with the object,the speed at which the object is moved results in the appropriate reactions such as oscillation.I'm fairly new to this cannot wrap my head around this.Can i get some help?i'm stuck and badly need this for a project.

Comment: Use Box2D engine, it already has all you might want about 2D-physics: http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Whatever you do, animation is statically defined, so should your object have to react on any external effect, you are better with a physics engine, thankfully there are several out there. Don't use animation for reflecting physics, it's a dead end.